# How to assign a value to a particular sequence in a column in r?

Tags: r

## Data

I have following data frame:

```
dm <- data.frame(vehid = rep(c(2,3), each=10),
                 frameid=rep(c(7,10,11,13,6,5,14,13,12,1),2),
                 frame.diff = rep(c(NA,3,1,2,7,1,9,1,1,11), 2),
                 s.frame = rep(c(rep(0,9), 12), 2))
```

## Question

For the `s.frame!=0` I want to detect all the `frameid` which are in the sequence of `frameid` to `s.frame` and assign a value `loop` to them and `.` to others.

## Desired Output

```
> dom
   vehid frameid frame.diff s.frame loop
1      2       7         NA       0 loop
2      2      10          3       0 loop
3      2      11          1       0 loop
4      2      13          2       0    .
5      2       6          7       0 loop
6      2       5          1       0 loop
7      2      14          9       0    .
8      2      13          1       0    .
9      2      12          1       0 loop
10     2       1         11      12 loop
11     3       7         NA       0 loop
12     3      10          3       0 loop
13     3      11          1       0 loop
14     3      13          2       0    .
15     3       6          7       0 loop
16     3       5          1       0 loop
17     3      14          9       0    .
18     3      13          1       0    .
19     3      12          1       0 loop
20     3       1         11      12 loop
```

In the above example, for both `vehid`s, the sequence was 1 to 12 (frameid:s.frame). The output shows the word 'loop' for the sequence and '.' for all others.
There should be a simple solution for this but I can't figure it out. I would appreciate if someone provide a `data.table` or `plyr` solution. Thanks.

Comment: Do you only have _one_ non zero element in "s.frame" for each "vehid"?

Comment: In my preliminary data exploration, there is only one non-zero element for a "vehid"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but here's a `data.table` option

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dm)[, loop := ifelse(frameid %between% c(frameid[s.frame != 0], s.frame[s.frame != 0]), "loop", "."), by = vehid]
dm

#     vehid frameid frame.diff s.frame loop
#  1:     2       7         NA       0 loop
#  2:     2      10          3       0 loop
#  3:     2      11          1       0 loop
#  4:     2      13          2       0    .
#  5:     2       6          7       0 loop
#  6:     2       5          1       0 loop
#  7:     2      14          9       0    .
#  8:     2      13          1       0    .
#  9:     2      12          1       0 loop
# 10:     2       1         11      12 loop
# 11:     3       7         NA       0 loop
# 12:     3      10          3       0 loop
# 13:     3      11          1       0 loop
# 14:     3      13          2       0    .
# 15:     3       6          7       0 loop
# 16:     3       5          1       0 loop
# 17:     3      14          9       0    .
# 18:     3      13          1       0    .
# 19:     3      12          1       0 loop
# 20:     3       1         11      12 loop
```

Comment: The sequence is 1:12 here, 1 in the `frameid` and 12 in the `s.frame`. It is not between the `min(s.frame)` and `max(s.frame)` because `min(s.frame)` is always equal to zero.

Comment: @umairdurrani isn't the output the desired? the same with `library(dplyr) dm %>%  mutate(loop = ifelse(frameid <= 12, 'loop', '.'))`

Comment: @PauloCardoso The output here matches the desired result but the code is not doing what is required. What the code does here is look at the min and max values of `s.frame` and treating that as a sequence, assign `loop` to that sequence. This is not required. The sequence I am looking at starts from the value in `frameid` where the corresponding `s.frame` is !=0 (which is 1 in this data frame) and ends at the corresponding `s.frame` value (which is 12 in this data frame). For all `frameid` between 1 to 12 the column `loop` should contain the string `"loop"`. Hope this is clear now.

Comment: @umairdurrani, see my edit. Hope this is what you were looking for

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thank you very much for your answers. This works fine for the sample data frame here. What if the `s.frame` has more than 1 non-zero value? Should I edit the question for including that kind of data?

Comment: What would be your desired output then?

Comment: I finally used my brain and with a bit of change in your code, achieved the desired output: `setDT(dm)[, p := ifelse(frameid%between% c(min(s.frame[s.frame !=0 ]), max(frameid[s.frame !=0])), "loop", "."), by = vehid]`. A bundle of thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dm %>% 
group_by(vehid) %>% 
mutate(loop= c(".", "loop")[(max(frameid[!!s.frame]) <= frameid & frameid <=  min(s.frame[!!s.frame]))+1])

#    vehid frameid frame.diff s.frame loop
# 1      2       7         NA       0 loop
# 2      2      10          3       0 loop
# 3      2      11          1       0 loop
# 4      2      13          2       0    .
# 5      2       6          7       0 loop
# 6      2       5          1       0 loop
# 7      2      14          9       0    .
# 8      2      13          1       0    .
# 9      2      12          1       0 loop
# 10     2       1         11      12 loop
# 11     3       7         NA       0 loop
# 12     3      10          3       0 loop
# 13     3      11          1       0 loop
# 14     3      13          2       0    .
# 15     3       6          7       0 loop
# 16     3       5          1       0 loop
# 17     3      14          9       0    .
# 18     3      13          1       0    .
# 19     3      12          1       0 loop
# 20     3       1         11      12 loop
```